# So I wanted to install something using pip install … but I get this error message, how can I fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, ujson, python-binance

```
Building wheels for collected packages: ujson
  Building wheel for ujson (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for ujson (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [128 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'ujson' extension
      creating build
      creating build/temp.macosx-13.2-arm64-cpython-311
      creating build/temp.macosx-13.2-arm64-cpython-311/deps
      creating build/temp.macosx-13.2-arm64-cpython-311/deps/double-conversion
      creating build/temp.macosx-13.2-arm64-cpython-311/deps/double-conversion/double-conversion
      creating build/temp.macosx-13.2-arm64-cpython-311/lib
      creating build/temp.macosx-13.2-arm64-cpython-311/python
      clang -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -O3 -Wall -miphoneos-version-min=14.0 -I/Users/holzschu/src/Xcode_iPad/a-Shell/cpython/Framew
orks_iphoneos/include -I./python -I./lib -I./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion -I/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4CA715BE-295E-4383-9963-3741287E37E5/a-Shell.app/Library/include/python3.11 -c ./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion/bignum-dtoa.cc -o build/temp.macosx-13.2-arm64-cpython-311/./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion/bignum-dtoa.o -D_GNU_SOURCE
      clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-miphoneos-version-min=14.0' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
      clang -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -O3 -Wall -miphoneos-version-min=14.0 -I/Users/holzschu/src/Xcode_iPad/a-Shell/cpython/Frameworks_iphoneos/include -I./python -I./lib -I./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion -I/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4CA715BE-295E-4383-9963-3741287E37E5/a-Shell.app/Library/include/python3.11 -c ./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion/bignum.cc -o build/temp.macosx-13.2-arm64-cpython-311/./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion/bignum.o -D_GNU_SOURCE
      clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-miphoneos-version-min=14.0' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
      clang -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -O3 -Wall -miphoneos-version-min=14.0 -I/Users/holzschu/src/Xcode_iPad/a-Shell/cpython/Frameworks_iphoneos/include -I./python -I./lib -I./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion -I/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4CA715BE-295E-4383-9963-3741287E37E5/a-Shell.app/Library/include/python3.11 -c ./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion/cached-powers.cc -o build/temp.macosx-13.2-arm64-cpython-311/./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion/cached-powers.o -D_GNU_SOURCE
      clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-miphoneos-version-min=14.0' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
      clang -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -O3 -Wall -miphoneos-version-min=14.0 -I/Users/holzschu/src/Xcode_iPad/a-Shell/cpython/Frameworks_iphoneos/include -I./python -I./lib -I./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion -I/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4CA715BE-295E-4383-9963-3741287E37E5/a-Shell.app/Library/include/python3.11 -c ./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion/double-to-string.cc -o build/temp.macosx-13.2-arm64-cpython-311/./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion/double-to-string.o -D_GNU_SOURCE
      clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-miphoneos-version-min=14.0' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
      clang -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -O3 -Wall -miphoneos-version-min=14.0 -I/Users/holzschu/src/Xcode_iPad/a-Shell/cpython/Frameworks_iphoneos/include -I./python -I./lib -I./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion -I/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4CA715BE-295E-4383-9963-3741287E37E5/a-Shell.app/Library/include/python3.11 -c ./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion/fast-dtoa.cc -o build/temp.macosx-13.2-arm64-cpython-311/./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion/fast-dtoa.o -D_GNU_SOURCE
      clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-miphoneos-version-min=14.0' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
      clang -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -O3 -Wall -miphoneos-version-min=14.0 -I/Users/holzschu/src/Xcode_iPad/a-Shell/cpython/Frameworks_iphoneos/include -I./python -I./lib -I./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion -I/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4CA715BE-295E-4383-9963-3741287E37E5/a-Shell.app/Library/include/python3.11 -c ./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion/fixed-dtoa.cc -o build/temp.macosx-13.2-arm64-cpython-311/./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion/fixed-dtoa.o -D_GNU_SOURCE
      clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-miphoneos-version-min=14.0' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
      clang -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -O3 -Wall -miphoneos-version-min=14.0 -I/Users/holzschu/src/Xcode_iPad/a-Shell/cpython/Frameworks_iphoneos/include -I./python -I./lib -I./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion -I/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4CA715BE-295E-4383-9963-3741287E37E5/a-Shell.app/Library/include/python3.11 -c ./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion/string-to-double.cc -o build/temp.macosx-13.2-arm64-cpython-311/./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion/string-to-double.o -D_GNU_SOURCE
      clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-miphoneos-version-min=14.0' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
      clang -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -O3 -Wall -miphoneos-version-min=14.0 -I/Users/holzschu/src/Xcode_iPad/a-Shell/cpython/Frameworks_iphoneos/include -I./python -I./lib -I./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion -I/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4CA715BE-295E-4383-9963-3741287E37E5/a-Shell.app/Library/include/python3.11 -c ./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion/strtod.cc -o build/temp.macosx-13.2-arm64-cpython-311/./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion/strtod.o -D_GNU_SOURCE
      clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-miphoneos-version-min=14.0' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
      clang -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -O3 -Wall -miphoneos-version-min=14.0 -I/Users/holzschu/src/Xcode_iPad/a-Shell/cpython/Frameworks_iphoneos/include -I./python -I./lib -I./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion -I/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4CA715BE-295E-4383-9963-3741287E37E5/a-Shell.app/Library/include/python3.11 -c ./lib/dconv_wrapper.cc -o build/temp.macosx-13.2-arm64-cpython-311/./lib/dconv_wrapper.o -D_GNU_SOURCE
      clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-miphoneos-version-min=14.0' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
      clang -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -O3 -Wall -miphoneos-version-min=14.0 -I/Users/holzschu/src/Xcode_iPad/a-Shell/cpython/Frameworks_iphoneos/include -I./python -I./lib -I./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion -I/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4CA715BE-295E-4383-9963-3741287E37E5/a-Shell.app/Library/include/python3.11 -c ./lib/ultrajsondec.c -o build/temp.macosx-13.2-arm64-cpython-311/./lib/ultrajsondec.o -D_GNU_SOURCE
      clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-miphoneos-version-min=14.0' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
      ./lib/ultrajsondec.c:69:65: warning: 'fastcall' calling convention is not supported for this target [-Wignored-attributes]
      static JSOBJ FASTCALL_MSVC decode_any( struct DecoderState *ds) FASTCALL_ATTR;
                                                                      ^
      ./lib/ultrajson.h:109:46: note: expanded from macro 'FASTCALL_ATTR'
              #define FASTCALL_ATTR __attribute__((fastcall))
                                                   ^
      ./lib/ultrajsondec.c:79:8: warning: 'fastcall' calling convention is not supported for this target [-Wignored-attributes]
      static FASTCALL_ATTR JSOBJ FASTCALL_MSVC decodeDouble(struct DecoderState *ds)
             ^
      ./lib/ultrajson.h:109:46: note: expanded from macro 'FASTCALL_ATTR'
              #define FASTCALL_ATTR __attribute__((fastcall))
                                                   ^
      ./lib/ultrajsondec.c:91:8: warning: 'fastcall' calling convention is not supported for this target [-Wignored-attributes]
      static FASTCALL_ATTR JSOBJ FASTCALL_MSVC decode_numeric (struct DecoderState *ds)
             ^
      ./lib/ultrajson.h:109:46: note: expanded from macro 'FASTCALL_ATTR'
              #define FASTCALL_ATTR __attribute__((fastcall))
                                                   ^
      ./lib/ultrajsondec.c:249:8: warning: 'fastcall' calling convention is not supported for this target [-Wignored-attributes]
      static FASTCALL_ATTR JSOBJ FASTCALL_MSVC decode_true ( struct DecoderState *ds)
             ^
      ./lib/ultrajson.h:109:46: note: expanded from macro 'FASTCALL_ATTR'
              #define FASTCALL_ATTR __attribute__((fastcall))
                                                   ^
      ./lib/ultrajsondec.c:269:8: warning: 'fastcall' calling convention is not supported for this target [-Wignored-attributes]
      static FASTCALL_ATTR JSOBJ FASTCALL_MSVC decode_false ( struct DecoderState *ds)
             ^
      ./lib/ultrajson.h:109:46: note: expanded from macro 'FASTCALL_ATTR'
              #define FASTCALL_ATTR __attribute__((fastcall))
                                                   ^
      ./lib/ultrajsondec.c:291:8: warning: 'fastcall' calling convention is not supported for this target [-Wignored-attributes]
      static FASTCALL_ATTR JSOBJ FASTCALL_MSVC decode_null ( struct DecoderState *ds)
             ^
      ./lib/ultrajson.h:109:46: note: expanded from macro 'FASTCALL_ATTR'
              #define FASTCALL_ATTR __attribute__((fastcall))
                                                   ^
      ./lib/ultrajsondec.c:311:8: warning: 'fastcall' calling convention is not supported for this target [-Wignored-attributes]
      static FASTCALL_ATTR void FASTCALL_MSVC SkipWhitespace(struct DecoderState *ds)
             ^
      ./lib/ultrajson.h:109:46: note: expanded from macro 'FASTCALL_ATTR'
              #define FASTCALL_ATTR __attribute__((fastcall))
                                                   ^
      ./lib/ultrajsondec.c:362:8: warning: 'fastcall' calling convention is not supported for this target [-Wignored-attributes]
      static FASTCALL_ATTR JSOBJ FASTCALL_MSVC decode_string ( struct DecoderState *ds)
             ^
      ./lib/ultrajson.h:109:46: note: expanded from macro 'FASTCALL_ATTR'
              #define FASTCALL_ATTR __attribute__((fastcall))
                                                   ^
      ./lib/ultrajsondec.c:589:8: warning: 'fastcall' calling convention is not supported for this target [-Wignored-attributes]
      static FASTCALL_ATTR JSOBJ FASTCALL_MSVC decode_array(struct DecoderState *ds)
             ^
      ./lib/ultrajson.h:109:46: note: expanded from macro 'FASTCALL_ATTR'
              #define FASTCALL_ATTR __attribute__((fastcall))
                                                   ^
      ./lib/ultrajsondec.c:653:8: warning: 'fastcall' calling convention is not supported for this target [-Wignored-attributes]
      static FASTCALL_ATTR JSOBJ FASTCALL_MSVC decode_object( struct DecoderState *ds)
             ^
      ./lib/ultrajson.h:109:46: note: expanded from macro 'FASTCALL_ATTR'
              #define FASTCALL_ATTR __attribute__((fastcall))
                                                   ^
      ./lib/ultrajsondec.c:747:8: warning: 'fastcall' calling convention is not supported for this target [-Wignored-attributes]
      static FASTCALL_ATTR JSOBJ FASTCALL_MSVC decode_any(struct DecoderState *ds)
             ^
      ./lib/ultrajson.h:109:46: note: expanded from macro 'FASTCALL_ATTR'
              #define FASTCALL_ATTR __attribute__((fastcall))
                                                   ^
      11 warnings generated.
      clang -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -O3 -Wall -miphoneos-version-min=14.0 -I/Users/holzschu/src/Xcode_iPad/a-Shell/cpython/Frameworks_iphoneos/include -I./python -I./lib -I./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion -I/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4CA715BE-295E-4383-9963-3741287E37E5/a-Shell.app/Library/include/python3.11 -c ./lib/ultrajsonenc.c -o build/temp.macosx-13.2-arm64-cpython-311/./lib/ultrajsonenc.o -D_GNU_SOURCE
      clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-miphoneos-version-min=14.0' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
      ./lib/ultrajsonenc.c:182:8: warning: 'fastcall' calling convention is not supported for this target [-Wignored-attributes]
      static FASTCALL_ATTR INLINE_PREFIX void FASTCALL_MSVC Buffer_AppendShortHexUnchecked (char *outputOffset, unsigned short value)
             ^
      ./lib/ultrajson.h:109:46: note: expanded from macro 'FASTCALL_ATTR'
              #define FASTCALL_ATTR __attribute__((fastcall))
                                                   ^
      ./lib/ultrajsonenc.c:541:8: warning: 'fastcall' calling convention is not supported for this target [-Wignored-attributes]
      static FASTCALL_ATTR INLINE_PREFIX void FASTCALL_MSVC Buffer_AppendCharUnchecked(JSONObjectEncoder *enc, char chr)
             ^
      ./lib/ultrajson.h:109:46: note: expanded from macro 'FASTCALL_ATTR'
              #define FASTCALL_ATTR __attribute__((fastcall))
                                                   ^
      ./lib/ultrajsonenc.c:563:8: warning: 'fastcall' calling convention is not supported for this target [-Wignored-attributes]
      static FASTCALL_ATTR INLINE_PREFIX void FASTCALL_MSVC strreverse(char* begin, char* end)
             ^
      ./lib/ultrajson.h:109:46: note: expanded from macro 'FASTCALL_ATTR'
              #define FASTCALL_ATTR __attribute__((fastcall))
                                                   ^
      3 warnings generated.
      clang -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -O3 -Wall -miphoneos-version-min=14.0 -I/Users/holzschu/src/Xcode_iPad/a-Shell/cpython/Frameworks_iphoneos/include -I./python -I./lib -I./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion -I/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4CA715BE-295E-4383-9963-3741287E37E5/a-Shell.app/Library/include/python3.11 -c ./python/JSONtoObj.c -o build/temp.macosx-13.2-arm64-cpython-311/./python/JSONtoObj.o -D_GNU_SOURCE
      clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-miphoneos-version-min=14.0' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
      In file included from ./python/JSONtoObj.c:41:
      In file included from /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4CA715BE-295E-4383-9963-3741287E37E5/a-Shell.app/Library/include/python3.11/Python.h:50:
      /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4CA715BE-295E-4383-9963-3741287E37E5/a-Shell.app/Library/include/python3.11/pyport.h:601:2: error: "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
      #error "LONG_BIT definition appears wrong for platform (bad gcc/glibc config?)."
       ^
      1 error generated.
      error: command '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4CA715BE-295E-4383-9963-3741287E37E5/a-Shell.app/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for ujson
Failed to build ujson
ERROR: Could not build wheels for ujson, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I’m using an iPad Air 5, my so version is 15.6.q and I’m using a-shell as my console to install that module

Answer (score -1):

the problem is not related to pip. its more likely related to deprecated code tho...
what python version are you using? i could install ujson 5.8.0 succesfully with python 3.10.6 and pip version 23.2.1

try:

```
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

and then:

```
    pip install ujson == 5.8.0
```

that worked for me

Comment: So I did try to install it but it tells me this;


Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Invalid requirement: '=='

Comment: what version of pip do you have?, you can check with pip --version

Comment: I have pip version 23.2.1 and python version 3.11.0 I fixed the error with the invalid requirement but I still get the same error message as my original error

Comment: have you tried installing ujson from the [source](https://github.com/ultrajson/ultrajson)?,

Comment: have you tried installing it with pip3? **pip3 install ujson**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).